# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Display problem

Tags: 20.04, display

[Lenovo idea 730] Display getting black stripes which eventually making the whole screen go black. I have recently installed ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

[image: Screenshot- 1]

[image: Screenshot- 2]

[Video Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HjZKcTFVAhdu_XUO1WVx-xBFm9hyjap0/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Do the black stripes grow or accumulate until the screen is completely black? What is the brand and model of your notebook? I wonder if this is a driver issue ...

Comment: Yes, I have attached a video link in the question description. Model is lenovo idea 730.